# How can I get the physical path of my web application in node.js (IIS)

Tags: node.js, iisnode

In asp.net, I can use Server.MapPath("~/") to get the root path of my application. Is there any environment variable I can access via process.env or any other method to get the root path in node.js? I'm using iisnode.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean absolute path of your project/application?

Comment: `console.log(process.cwd())` for the current working directory or for the current file `console.log(__dirname)`

Comment: @TienDuong, I want the root of the application - the physical folder that has been configured in IIS for the current website.

Comment: @RolandStarke, thanks that works. But what I want is the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one ways to do that:

`__dirname`  - The directory of the current module

`__filename` - The full path to the current module

`process.cwd()` - The working directory of the app

Comment: All of these give me the folder of the current .js file. What I want to obtain is the folder where the IIS app is installed - c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\. The above commands give me c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\user\adduser

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, I am wondering why the question did not describe the IIS configuration.  If IIS is configured with a virtual folder or IIS added an application to the root server, the folder that is returned with the three options described above, will describe the folder that was set in IIS.  This is exactly what I see when testing this answer - it works for me!  Thanks Charlie...